# Generating a plot with tikzDevice and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, tikzdevice

I can't get tikzDevice to work with ggplot2. I have taken a mwe from another question: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322091/plotsizes-plotting-with-ggplot2-in-r-and-using-tikzdevice

But it is producing an empty file, just with a heading as follows.

```
% Created by tikzDevice version 0.12.3 on 2019-08-22 11:31:02
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicod
```

I've looked and looked but I have not found a solution. I am aware that this is the same question as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442878/r-code-ggplot-not-outputting-to-tex-file) but the solution does not work for me.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
require(grid)
library(tikzDevice)

tikz(file = "my_output_file1.tex", 
     standAlone=F,
     width = 7, 
     height = 3
)

cars['dt'] = seq(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date()-980,-20)

plot1 <- ggplot(cars,aes(y=speed,x=dist,color=as.integer(dt)))+
  geom_point(size=2,alpha=0.7)+
  xlab("distance")+
  ylab("speed")+
  scale_color_gradientn("dt",
                        colours=rainbow(6)
  )+

  #textsize

  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position="right",
        legend.key.height=unit(2,"lines"),
        legend.title=element_text(size=rel(0.8)),
        legend.text=element_text(size=rel(0.8)),
        axis.text.y=element_text(angle=90, 
                                 hjust=0.5),
        axis.title=element_text(size=rel(0.8)),

        aspect.ratio = 2/(1+sqrt(5))
  ) 

print(plot1)     

dev.off()
```

On the contrary if I just do the following it works:

```
tikz(file = "balls.tex", 
     standAlone=F,
     width = 7, 
     height = 3
)
# Define the ball vector with 5 values
balls <- c(2, 4, 3, 8, 9)

pl<-plot(balls)
print(pl)     
plot(pl)
dev.off()
```

In both cases I get the same warning message:

```
Measuring dimensions of: \char77
Running command: "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe" -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error -output-directory "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpI3Rsqu\tikzDevice36d07d7b1ee5" "tikzStringWidthCalc.tex"
Error in getMetricsFromLatex(TeXMetrics, verbose = verbose) : 
TeX was unable to calculate metrics for:

    \char77

Run the following commands for diagnosis:

    tikzTest()
    tikzTest("\\char77")

Common reasons for failure include:
  * The string contains a character which is special to LaTeX unless
    escaped properly, such as % or $.
  * The string makes use of LaTeX commands provided by a package and
    the tikzDevice was not told to load the package.

The TeX and log files used for the calculation can help diagnose the
problem. If these files are missing, rerun the plot and make sure to
keep the R session open.
TeX file: tikzStringWidthCalc.tex
Log file: tikzStringWidthCalc.log
```

Where do I start finding out where my problem is?

Here is the output of 
tikzDevice::tikzTest()

```
Active compiler:
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe
    MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6050 (1.40.17) (MiKTeX 2.9)
    Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2016 Han The Thanh

Measuring dimensions of: A
Running command: "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe" -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error -output-directory "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpI3Rsqu\tikzDevice36d045155d2e" "tikzStringWidthCalc.tex"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode

======================================================================

Unfortunately, the package preview could not be installed.Please check the log file:
C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log
======================================================================

TeX was unable to calculate metrics for:

    A
```

Contents of TeX file tikzStringWidthCalc.tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[active,tightpage,psfixbb]{preview}

\PreviewEnvironment{pgfpicture}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{0pt}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\batchmode
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=1] (TeX) {A};
\path let \p1 = ($(TeX.east) - (TeX.west)$),
    \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in (TeX.east) -- (TeX.west)
    node{ \typeout{tikzTeXWidth=\n1} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Contents of log file tikzStringWidthCalc.log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.10.19)  22 AUG 2019 13:18
entering extended mode
**./tikzStringWidthCalc.tex
(tikzStringWidthCalc.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls
"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\frontendlaye
r\tikz.sty"
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\p
gf.sty"
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pg
frcs.sty"
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\
pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\
pgfutil-common-lists.tex"))
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\
pgfutil-latex.def"
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty"
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\
pgfrcs.code.tex"
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\p
gfcore.sty"
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphic
x.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.
sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphic
s.sty"
Package: graphics 2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.st
y"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphic
s.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdf
tex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwa
rerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcm
ds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\
pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlaye
r\pgfsys.code.tex"
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\
pgfkeys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\
pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count88
\c@pgf@countb=\count89
\c@pgf@countc=\count90
\c@pgf@countd=\count91
\t@pgf@toka=\toks19
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks21

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlaye
r\pgf.cfg"
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlaye
r\pgfsys-pdftex.def"
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2014/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.35)

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlaye
r\pgfsys-common-pdf.def"
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlaye
r\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex"
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count92
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count93
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlaye
r\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex"
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
))
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.st
y"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.c
fg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcore.code.tex"
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
th.code.tex"
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
thcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
thutil.code.tex")
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
thparser.code.tex"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count94
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
thfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
thfunctions.basic.code.tex")
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
thfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex")
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
thfunctions.random.code.tex")
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
thfunctions.comparison.code.tex")
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
thfunctions.base.code.tex")
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
thfunctions.round.code.tex")
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
thfunctions.misc.code.tex")
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
thfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
thfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count95
))
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcorepoints.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcorescopes.code.tex"
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count96
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex"
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcoretransformations.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcorearrows.code.tex"
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count97
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcoreimage.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcorelayers.code.tex"
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcoretransparency.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer
\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pg
fmoduleshapes.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pg
fmoduleplot.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibilit
y\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibilit
y\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pg
ffor.sty"
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pg
fkeys.sty"
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\
pgfkeys.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\math\pgfmath
.sty"
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
th.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\
pgffor.code.tex"
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfma
th.code.tex")
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
))
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendla
yer\tikz\tikz.code.tex"
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\
pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex"
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count98
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box36
\tikztreelevel=\count99
\tikznumberofchildren=\count100
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count101
\tikz@fig@count=\count102

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pg
fmodulematrix.code.tex"
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count103
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count104
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count105
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count106

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendla
yer\tikz\libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))

! LaTeX Error: File `preview.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.6 

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10652 strings out of 493334
 224363 string characters out of 3129355
 250475 words of memory out of 3000000
 14037 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 55i,0n,54p,403b,86s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: You code works for me. What is the output of `tikzDevice::tikzTest()`? What is the content of `tikzStringWidthCalc.tex` and `tikzStringWidthCalc.log`?

Comment: The problem is that the `preview` package is not installed in your tex distribution (which is by the way very old). You should try to update miktex

Comment: I see! I don't have admin rights, so while I wait for the admin to make the updates I added: ```options(tikzDefaultEngine = 'pdftex')
options(tikzLatex = 'C:/texlive/2019/bin/win32/pdflatex.exe')``` as I have a more recent version of texlive already installed... and... it works!